# Cannot resolve method 'intValue()'

Tags: java, int, double

I am trying to create a get method for a private double variable.

When I write

```
public class {

  private double x = 4.12;

  public int get(){
    double temp = new Double(this.x);
    return temp.intValue();
  }

}
```

The IDE suggest to remove Double `Unnecessary boxing 'new Double(this.x)'` and it does not recognize intValue() method. The same goes when just writing:

```
return this.x.intValue();
```

Comment: I would suggest to change the return and cast type to long. Since double might be holding a number greater than the size of int type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitives don't have methods, and there's no point in creating a new instance of `Double` only to immediately unwrap it again.

Cast instead:

```
return (int) this.x;
```

Answer (score 2):

`double` and `Double` are different. `double` is a primitive type, it has no methods attached. `Double` is class with methods attached. To convert between them, use type casting.

```
public int get(){
    return  ((Double) x).intValue();
}
```

Every primitive type (`int`, `float`, `char`, etc.) has a *wrapper class*. They usually have the same name, but with with the first letter capitalised. The compiler often automatically converts between the primitive and the wrapper, but sometimes we have to help it by explicitly type casting.

Comment: Right, my bad. Edited!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be storing temp in a primitive double, but you need to use the class:

```
Double temp = new Double(this.x);
```

Also, don't use new `Double(...)`. Use `Double.valueOf(...)`:

```
Double temp = Double.valueOf(this.x);
```

Comment: If you actually needed a `Double` (which you don't) a cleaner way to do it would be `Double temp = this.x;`.

Comment: @AndyTurner What if OP has a reason to store it as a `Double` and just didn't show the rest of the code for simplicity?

Comment: "Guess what OP meant" is a wild and infinitely deep rabbit hole. Best just to stick to what's actually shown.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you're assigning it to primitive double type. 
Try this -

```
Double temp = new Double(this.x);
return temp.intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `temp` is declared `double` not `Double` and `new Double(this.x)` creates a `Double` and unboxes it to a `double`. That is why the compiler complains about `Unnecessary boxing...`.

You could simply use `return new Double(this.x).intValue();` instead.

Comment: I get 'Double(double)' is deprecated

Comment: @gbox [the deprecation is explained in Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#%3Cinit%3E(double)).